# TCP Connection in Web application

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I really need your advice on this.
I have many TCP Client Devices.  The Web application is going to be accessed by many users after an authentication.
The problem I need to solve is -

1. Create a TCP Listener for these client machines and that should be accessed by every user -
   Solution I think - create a tcp connection on a page. Every user will create a new tcp connection from their device(local host) once the page is load . This is possible because every user pc is diferent so  its going to be entirely different connection. But this solution is not going with problem 2.
2. The Machine broadcasts data every 30 seconds. So my application should be able to catch that data and update on the page.
   This is I think is the main problem.

I know live data update on a web page can be done using SignalR. But SignalR does not connect with TCP Client machine directly. So what I was trying to do is -

1st - I tried making a WCF Service for TCP listener. WCF service will get data from machine and save into database from where signalR will do its job. But Whenever I am using wcf service my system is getting hang. So I dont know if its a right way to do that.

2nd - I tried creating Windows service as tcp listener. But I dont think its gonna work with web application.

To be very frank, I am not able to understand what should I do for this functionality.

From my side - I just want a TCP connection on application level that should be persistent, independent of user and should not close on any page reload.
Whenever that connection receives data it should be updated on every user's web browser without any reload.

I cannot use timer. It should be realtime.

According to what I found and understood, TCP connection is with a device so signalR can not be used directly. We need something else(like a service) in between to make it work with signalR.

So at the end, What should I do? 
I hope I am clear enough to state my problem. 
I just want to discuss so that my doubts can get clear and I may find the desired result at the end.

## EDIT 1 :

In websocket, signalR... normally client refers to web browser.
Can a device(Multimedia control device) be a client similar to web browser for signalR?

Comment: Browsers *are* TCP Clients. SignalR works on top of HTTP, not just TCP though. Typically it works using web sockets. You should probably explain the actual problem, not what you tried to solve it. IoT devices for example should **never** be called directly for security reasons. *They* should contact the server and send data, retrieve commands from it. If they can handle Web sockets, they can receive messages from the server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos... My Issue is - I have a Control device that broadcast data(status of its various control), uses TCP for transfer. I want to listen continuously to the specific port(1200 in this case)  so that whenever that control device(TCP Client) broadcasts, I catch that data and do some process and show it on web page without any user interaction(no reload or no  refresh and not any button click from user).

Comment: So you have an IoT problem, and you want the *IoT device* to call the web server. You don't need TcpListener or SignalR for that. You could use any TCP or HTTP library availalbe for your device to make HTTP POST calls to a server. You can find TCP/HTTP libraries for Arduino or even ESP8266 devices. There are more appropriate protocols for IoT communications though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. I am very sorry...but I am not introduced to this concept at all. So if you dont mind to explain a little bit more about your comment above and specially this line **You could use any HTTP library availalbe for your device to make HTTP calls to a server.**

Comment: There are frameworks and services for IoT communications, command and control. Azure and Amazon already provice full data ingestion, control, management and *update* services for IoT. You should check them first, see how they work. Even if you decide to roll your own functionality you should check their architecture, how they handle problems. What if you *can't* connect to the server immediatelly? Do you *stop* the device? Or do you cache messages until you can reconnect?

Comment: In this case I'd suggest you find an IoT course and tutorials *before* writing code. Buy your own Arduino, ESP8266 and start playing at home, check hobbyist projects. Understand how things work before you start coding. [This hobbyist project](https://www.instructables.com/id/Programming-a-HTTP-Server-on-ESP-8266-12E/) shows how you can create and run your own server on top of an ESP8266, a *very* weak device. You shouldn't use that in production though - there's no way you can protect such small devices with firewalls or anti-malware programs

Comment: [This tutorial](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/client-examples.html) shows how to use the *WiFiClient* class to construct HTTP messages as plain strings, and handle the client/server communication in code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. I have some more doubts now.. but I think I should see this tutorial first , may be my doubts get clear and if not then I will query again.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. One more Question Sir... This was the half of the task. Another was... The user will have a web page with buttons(that is similar to remote control of that device). When user clicks the button it should command the device to do the following task. This means device will broadcast on itself and will listen to commands also by user. This case also comes under  IoT as it is related to sending the data to a physical device over network.. Am I right?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.. What other scenerios do we have here because I dont really feel the need of IoT here. The client device I am using here can communicate to server by itself. Its just my server that should be up always for listening.